# Two tab bar items should show the same UIViewContoller

Tags: ios, ios5

What I want is to have two UITabBarItems in my UITabBar (thats not really the problem...).

So normally the first item has his own an UIViewcontroller and the second item has his own UIViewcontroller.
But I want that each TabBarItem shows the same UIViewcontroller instance.
(the functionality is nearly the same, only one label is different between those two viewcontrollers)

So I think I have to push the last viewController on top of the tabBarItemStack right after the user pushed the second tabBarItem, right ?

At the moment I'm using a StoaryBoard  with two UIViewcontroller, so I really don't know how I can access the TabBarItemStack and where do I get the notification that the next tab is pushed by the user ?

Or can I alter the stack after loading the first view and push the current view on the second index of the stack ?

Hope I was able to explain my problem so anybody would understand ;-)

Thanks and Regards,

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use the UITabBar at all in this case. I would make some GUI-object in my viewcontroller that looks like two tabs, but is acually just 2 buttons.

When you click them you switch their look so that it looks like you have switched tabs, by changing the images of the buttons. But you are always staying in the same viewcontroller all the time. And you just change the content in it.

Then you can keep track class which "tab" the user has selected by using member variables and that way you know which content to show.

The UITabBar is most useful when you have an unknown amount of tabs and you don't know exactly what they will contain. There are many times it is a lot easier to not use the UITabBar and just images/buttons with "tab-looking" layout, even when you have more than one viewcontroller.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestions. This sounds actually quite good. But I'm not sure if I will need more tabs in the future so that I have 3 tabs, two of them are like described above and one or even more are totally different. So if there is a possibility to realize it like a mentioned above I would prefer this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Could you have two `UIViewController`s (one for each `UITabBarItem`), but they are both inherited (descended) from a third (Which contains all the logic).  That way you are not duplicating the code, and not faffing with the hierarchy, such that you might introduce bugs?

Comment: Well thats what I first though too. But then I still have tow instances of the VC and have the syncronize some variables between both. Thts why I want the same instace of the VC.

Answer (score 0):

Load same UIViewController in both TabBar. I assume u need to hide label in first tabBar and show in second tabBar

Now in viewWillAppear Method add this code:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   if(self.tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0) 
   {
      yourLabel.hidden = YES;
   }
   else if(self.tabBarController.selectedIndex == 1) 
   {
      yourLabel.hidden = NO;
   }
}
```

Comment: Load same UIViewController in both TabBarController ? Well I do not have two TabBarControllers but one with two items. So how can I load the same instace of the VC to both items?

Comment: my mistake : Load same UIViewController in both TabBar.

Comment: Well Ok but how ? ;-) Sorry but I stand on my head at the moment. Thanks